# Can a Wcf Channel Factory be used in concurrent operations?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a legacy c# code that is creating a new WCF channel factory for every call. I am intending to reuse the channel factory but I have a concern about whether the same IRequestChannel object be used to invoke concurrent calls in a Parallel.For loop

Comment: The information I got from your description is difficult to reproduce the problem. However, there is documentation for using asynchronous operations in WCF Channel Factory. [How to: Call Operations Asynchronously Using a Channel Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-call-operations-asynchronously-using-a-channel-factory?redirectedfrom=MSDN)